# Simplification of expression (related to multinomial theorem)

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Is there a simplified way to write the following:
$$\sum_{r_1+r_2+\cdots+r_n=t,r_k\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{t!}{r_1!r_2!\cdots r_n!}\prod_{k=1}^nf(k)^{r_k}$$
This is very similar to the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) formula, however instead of $r_k$ being non-negative, $r_k$ is a natural number. In an expansion this is equivalent to just taking the values where every term is exponentiated to a power of one or greater, for example in the expansion of $(a+b+c)^4$ just taking $3(2a^2bc+2ab^2c+2abc^2)$.

Comment: You haven´t explained what $f(k)$ is.

Comment: Why are negative factorials necessary to calculate the coefficients of the expansion of $(a+b+c)^4$? Can you give more context?

Comment: @callculus Look at the multinomial theorem, they use $x_k$ instead of $f(k)$. This formula is the literally the same as the multinomial theorem except for the values of $r_k$ can't be 0.

Comment: @LegNaiB negative factorials?

Comment: I thought the indices were from $\mathbb{Z}$ :D

Answer (score 1):

Obviously $t>n$, otherwise the sum is empty, so you could just take the multinomial coefficient
$$
\binom{t-n}{r_1,...,r_n}
$$
where each $r_i \in \{0,1,2,...\}$ and then you just add $1$ to each exponent. That works as in the original question each $r_i$ is at least one, so we can just remove that and subtract $n$ times $1$ from the top of the multinomial coefficient. This yields the final formula
$$
\sum_{r_1+...+r_n=t-n} \binom{t-n}{r_1,...,r_n}\prod_{k=1}^nf(k)^{r_k+1}
$$
which simplifies using the multinomial theorem to
$$
\prod_{k=1}^nf(k) \cdot \left(\sum_{r_1+...+r_n=t-n} \binom{t-n}{r_1,...,r_n}\prod_{k=1}^nf(k)^{r_k}\right) = \prod_{k=1}^n f(k)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)\right)^{t-n}
$$

Comment: Could I then factor out $\prod_{k=1}^n f(k)$ and turn what's left into $\left(\sum_{k=1}^nf(k)\right)^{t-n}$

Comment: Yeah that seems viable, I add that to my answer